# Why doesn't the directory I created appear in both Gallery and Google Photos?

Tags: java, android

In my `CameraFragment.java` I have a library called `nataro1 CameraView` which basically allows me to open up the device's camera and take a photo. That photo is saved in a directory created by the app, called "Feel". Everything works fine, the directory is created and the photos are stored there. The problem is, whenever I try to see them in the Gallery or in Google Photos, I can't. There is no directory and no photos. If I want to see them I must go to "Settings/Storage/InternalStorage/Explore/Pictures". Why can't I see the directory in Gallery and in Google Photos?
This is the code I have:

```
 private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, String image_name) {

    final String appDirectoryName = "/Feel"; // Nome da pasta onde irão ser guardadas as fotos
    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + appDirectoryName; // Caminho do root da galeria do telemóvel
    File myDir = new File(root); // Declara um novo ficheiro com o nome do root + "/Feel"
    if(!myDir.exists()){ // Caso o diretório ainda não exista...
        myDir.mkdirs(); // ... cria um com esse nome
    }
    String fname = "Image" + image_name + ".jpg"; // Concatena o nome da imagem com a extensão ".JPG"
    File file = new File(myDir, fname); // Declara um novo ficheiro com o caminho e o nome da imagem
    Log.i("LOAD", root + fname);
    try { // Caso dê erro...
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); // Declara um OutputStream
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out); // Cria e comprime o ficheiro
        out.flush();
        out.close(); // Fecha o output
    } catch (Exception e) { // ... não dá crash
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some extra code to view your picture in the gallery.

```
// Mention your file
String filePath=imageFile.getPath();

// add this code to view the picture in gallery
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { filePath }, new String[] { "image/jpeg" }, null);
```

Comment: That `"image/jpeg"`, do I need to change it to be equal to my image or I just leave it like that?

Comment: depends on your image type, see mime types here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385520/android-available-mime-types

Comment: Oh, ok, it's jpeg like you said. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun notifyGallery(photo: File) {

        // the listner inside mediascanner runs on binder thread that why handler post method to execute inside ui thread for showing toast and notidication
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(photo.absolutePath), null) { path, uri ->
            Handler(context.mainLooper).post({
                Toast.makeText(context, "${photo.name} saved to gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })
        }
}
```

Comment: what does this add to the existing answer?

Comment: it shows how to use MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener as it runs on binder thread if any UI related stuff is to be done it should be on UI thread